# Property used like a variable in BGE

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

In BGE I want to use an object's property like a variable (for example to simulate speed increment for a car). How could I do it using a python script? And in this case could I use only "sensors" and "controllers" (using a python script as a "controller") without using "actuators"?

Sorry for my English. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

You can see a property as "game object variable". This means it is part of the game object. (A variable is an separate object within a specific context e.g. a function).

Accessing a property the same like dictionary access.

**Without check for existence:**

```
propertyValue = gameObject[propertyName]
```

This fits in most situations. If the property does not exist you get a KeyError.

**With pre-check:**

```
if propertyName in gameObject:
    propertyValue = gameObject[propertyName]
```

This is a good situation when you can't guaranty the property is set, but you do not call this code very often.

**With error handling:**

```
try:
    propertyValue = gameObject[propertyName]
except KeyError:
    print("Warning: '{}' in {} does not exist.".format(propertyName, gameObject.name))
```

This is good when you expect the property might not be set and this situation is no reason to stop and this code is called very often (faster than pre-check).

**With default value:**

```
propertyValue = gameObject.get(propertyName, defaultValue)
```

This is good when you do not want to stop if the property is not set. In this case the default value will be given. Attention: The property will still not be set!

If you skip the default value, the default value is `None`. Be aware the default value is always evaluated, regardless if the property exists or not. Therefore the default value should be fast to get e.g. already exist or it is a primitive type such as numbers or strings.

**Adding/updateing:**

```
gameObject[propertyName] = newValue
```